# FQDN from mono with dotnet on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, mono, .net-core, powershell-cmdlet

If `Powershell Core` on Linux, [using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48844667/262852) `dotnet`, can return the `FQDN`, then how does `mono`, also using `dotnet`, get the same result?

Here's `powershell` finding the [local system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821192/262852) `FQDN`:

```
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell$ pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName((hostname)).HostName                                        
dur.bounceme.net
PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```

and `mono`:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ mono Projects/console/console/bin/Debug/console.exe
Hello Mono World
dur
dur

localhost
localhost
localhost
dur
done
thufir@dur:~$ 


code:

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace console
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {



        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");

            String name;

            name = Environment.MachineName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

             name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine(name);

             name = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            name =System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").HostName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            name = Dns.GetHostEntry("LocalHost").HostName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            // var ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            //   name = string.Format("{0}.{1}", ipProperties.HostName, ipProperties.DomainName);
            //  Console.WriteLine(name);

            name = Dns.GetHostEntry("LocalHost").HostName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);


            Console.WriteLine("done");

        }
    }
}
```

thanks to jjw for pointing me in the right direction.

This is tantalizingly close, because `dur`, which is how the prompt is shown, is listed.  Just not the whole name.  Also:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ hostname
dur
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ hostname --fqdn
dur.bounceme.net
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dur.bounceme.net    dur

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
dur
thufir@dur:~$
```

Looking for the whole enchilada here, not just the prepend of `dur` but `dur.bounceme.net` if possible.  **Because `Powershell Core` can find the `FQDN` shouldn't `mono` be able to do the same**?

Comment: The system may not have a FQDN. It may only be a hostname. *`localhost`* is a hostname;  *`localhost.localdomain.`* is a FQDN.

Comment: @jww it has a FQDN.  Even localhost.localdomain would be output.  currently, no output at all.

Comment: Maybe you can try Mono's [Howto IpInfobyDns](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/howto_ipinfobydns/). It looks like the Mono sample is using a static method `Dns.GetHostName()`. `hostname --fqdn` is different. It is a command written in C against OS API's (not a language runtime) and I am not sure how it behaves nowadays. I know how it is supposed to behave, but that may not happen.

Comment: There is also [Get FQDN in C# running on Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17114536/608639), [How do I get the local machine name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662282/608639), [How to get full host name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37087949/608639), etc on Stack Overflow. The second one seems like it should help: `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName;`. It might be a good idea to perform a quick search: [Mono+hostname+site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mono+retrieve+hostname+site:stackoverflow.com).